# Receive Mails with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer

I would like to scrap mails from a MailBox, this is the situation:

It's about a Technical support with a Ticket System.

A client make a demand on the contact form on the website,
The ticket have a page with a chat and a task list made by the admin in charge of the ticket, so a link to this page is sent to the client who made the demand,

Then when the Admin answer to the ticket in the chat, a mail is sent to the Client, everything to there is ok, the problem is that when the client answer to this email, the content of the mail must be scrapped and added to the database to be seen in the Ticket Chat.

So the Idea is that the Client Can follow the progress of his Ticket by mail instead of going to the ticket page.

I've tried MailMan, but that didn't work, the deamon was starting and then crashed after a couple of minutes whitout scrapping anything, I don't use SendGrid but a private SMTP server so I can't use the Grabber gem of this service.

I'm running Rails 5, my DB is in PostGre, and I'm using ActionMailer as mailing system.

I'm running out of ideas about how to make this feature..

I hope my question is clear enough and my English not too bad.

Comment: Have you tried griddler? http://griddler.io/

Comment: That requires using of  SendGrid, Cloudmailin, Postmark or Mandrill, that's what I was talking when I mentioned the grabber thing. =/

Comment: What's your question? You want code, tutorial? Probably your question is too broad.

Comment: Last mailman updates are a little bit old. I think until now they don't support rails 5. I would try to fetch mails via getmail on linux and send them via stdin to rails runner script. Ruby on Rails guide "Action Mailer Basics" describes how ActionMailer can read an email from stdin and work with this data.

Comment: Yes I saw that, that was a bit a blur to me but i'm gonna give another eye on it, thanks for answering.

And i'm Open to any answer, code, examples, tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to make an email(any popular provider *except gmail*) box and configure it to use the pop server. To read it from box use the [`mail`](https://github.com/mikel/mail#getting-emails-from-a-pop-server) gem.

```
Mail.defaults do
  retriever_method :pop3, :address    => "pop.supermail.com",
                          :port       => 995,
                          :user_name  => '<username>',
                          :password   => '<password>',
                          :enable_ssl => true
end
```

Then make a daemon to read all income emails and save it to the database, [`mail`](https://github.com/mikel/mail) gem is just a wrapper around [`Net::POP3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/pop/rdoc/Net/POP3.html) ruby library and it is super useful for read\receive\parse\build mails.

The `ActionMailer` here is not a helper for you, it is very handy only for send mails and it does nothing to recieve mail.

Comment: I'll try that, Thanks a lot